# How to list what changed during a merge in Git?

Tags: git, merge

Something I still haven't gotten my head wrapped around with regards to using Git is how do I list 'what changed' as a result of a merge in Git?  Ultimately, I just want a list of files that were modified as a result of the merge.

I'm thinking that maybe I do something like this? 'git diff --name-only '

Just so you know, I am using 'non-fast-forwarded' merges.

thx

Answer (score 2):

I like

`git diff --stat HEAD..HEAD^`

That gives you filenames and a one-line listing of the number of changed lines in the file. It's handy to know what changed a little and what changed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just did `git merge`, and ended up with the merge commit as your head.  You can check the changes from the merge commit by doing:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^
```

Which will list all of the files that changed between your head and the previous commit.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for: `git diff --name-status <merge-commit>^1 <merge-commit>^2`.  This seems to be giving me what I want, especially if I want to look at a merge that happened in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Should be this one

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

HEAD^ is your merge commit
HEAD is your head of your branch